# Sending email notification on error using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am currently implementing Send Email notification on error in my SSIS package. It currently works. Just want to check if this is the right way of doing it.
[image]

Comment: will you be able to schedule it as a job in `SQL Server Agent` or not?

Comment: Make sure the red constraints are OR, not AND, otherwise an email will only be sent if _everything_ fails

Comment: questions like this are better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LONG why did you ask about agent?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to trigger your mail task when **any** error occurs, consider the "Event Handlers".

This SimpleTask article provides a very good overview of the event handlers
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-event-handlers-basics/

> SSIS event handlers are the simplest means of turning an SSIS script into a reliable system that is auditable, reacts appropriately to error conditions, reports progress and allows instrumentation and monitoring your SSIS packages. They are easy to implement, and provide a great deal of flexibility.

Sample screen shot:
[image]

Using event handler provides some advantage - you need not connect each task's failure. The system will call your event handler for the error.

Also, note there are 2 event handlers of interest:
OnError

OnTaskFailed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-event-handlers

> OnError event - This event is raised when an error occurs.
>
> OnTaskFailed event - This event is raised by a task when it fails.

One thing to watch out for is that you event handler may be called multiple times depending on the number of errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no standard answer to this question. But here are some of the tips that I am be able to think of.

First, not very sure what kind of plain text you are trying to send out, if they do not have dynamic text body, you could put that `send email task` in the `event handlers` right to the `Control flow, Data Flow...` tab, and put that `on error` for specific tasks.

Second, I personally do not prefer to use `Failure` output, you may need to increase the number of `MaximumErrorCount` so that the package could executed successfully, but sometimes the real error might not be detected because together with error output, the total error numbers is still less than the threshold.

Third, if you are sending the same text, and you will schedule it as a job in `SQL Server Agent`, you could go to `Notifications` option page, set the `Send Email`, basically it will be informative.

Last but not least, the `Send Mail task` supports plain text only, not any formatting like email coded by `html` & `CSS`, if you need to take the formatting into consideration, that might not be your choice, you could use `Script task` using `C#` or creating `html` page by using `XML` statement from your `SSMS` and put into a stored procedure, then sent out the `html` by `Database Mail`, you will find this tool under `Management` folder in your `SSMS`.

Comment: Does SQL agent notification report ssis error details like description and error code?

Comment: Why do you say "basically it will be informative." for email from agent job?